# Tax free for specific products for users in a customer group

Tags: magento2, tax

I have setup a customer group "Tax Exempt", which works fine but it only works for ALL products.

I want the users in "Tax Exempt" to only receive tax free on specific products. Is there a way to do this out of the box?

This is exactly what I'm looking for.

User 1 : Customer Group: (Tax Exempt)

Product 1: Charge Taxes for Customer Group: (Tax Exempt)

Product 2: No Taxes for Customer Group: (Tax Exempt)

Product 3: Charge Taxes for Customer Group: (Tax Exempt)

Etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create some 'Product Tax Classes' and assign the correct product tax classes to the correct products.

Then create the Tax Rules combination :
(Customer Tax Class + Product Tax Class + Tax Rate)

Let me know if something is not clear.